# Creating foreign key using raw MySql statement in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Since I know how to use mySql raw statements and Laravel fluent queries confuse me a bit, specially ones for creating tables, I would like to create tables by using raw SQL statements.

Tables without foreign keys were created successfully, but I am getting error message when trying to create table with foreign key. For example, the following code

```
$sql_kreiraj_Prof="
    CREATE TABLE profesori(
       ProfID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
       ime CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
       prezime CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
       k_ime CHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
       sifra CHAR(15) NOT NULL)";
try {
    $sql_postoji="SELECT 1 FROM profesori LIMIT 1";
}
catch(Exception $e){
    DB::statement($sql_kreiraj_Prof);
}


$sql_kreiraj_Predmet="
    CREATE TABLE predmeti(
      PredmetID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
      naziv CHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      semestar ENUM ('I','II','III','IV','V','VI','VII','VIII','IX','X') NOT NULL,
      dan ENUM ('Ponedjeljak','Utorak','Srijeda','Četvrtak','Petak') NOT NULL,
      rbr_casa INTEGER NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY (predavacID)
        REFERENCES profesori (ProfID)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE)";
try {
    $sql_postoji="SELECT 1 FROM predmeti LIMIT 1";
}
catch(Exception $e){
    DB::statement($sql_kreiraj_Predmet);
}
```

Results with the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'predavacID' doesn't exist in table (SQL: CREATE TABLE predmeti...

I am trying to figure this one out for a while now, so any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be very welcome.

Comment: What about using laravel [migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations)?

Also laravel has DB:select() for queries and DB::statement() for running statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Key column 'predavacID' doesn't exist in table

That error is pretty clear. You're trying to make `predavacID` into a foreign key, but no column by that name exists. You either need to choose one of the integer columns in the `predmeti` table, or else declare the column `predavacID` before you make it a foreign key.

A foreign key constraint does not implicitly create a column. The column must exist on its own.